# How to add FishEye distortion to UIImage using GPUImage or any other Lib?

Tags: ios, gpuimage, fisheye

I am using GPUImage for adding filters on UIImage. GPUImage does not contain fish eye distortion effect, I need shader code for fish eye distortion effect which could be used in GPUImage custom filter.

Comment: did you manage to complete this one? any starting point?

Comment: NSString *const kGPUImageFishEyeFragmentShaderString=SHADER_STRING (varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate; uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
 const mediump float bulgeFactor = 0.5;  void main() { mediump vec2 processedTextureCoordinate = textureCoordinate - vec2(0.5);  mediump float radius = processedTextureCoordinate.x*processedTextureCoordinate.x + processedTextureCoordinate.y*processedTextureCoordinate.y; mediump vec2 distortedCoordinate = vec2(pow(radius, bulgeFactor))*processedTextureCoordinate + vec2(0.5); gl_FragColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, distortedCoordinate); }); Try this